# Test de Hilos de Java (elemental) no parece funcionar correctamente

Tags: java, hilos

Se trata de un test de sincronización de hilos y la salida que obtengo es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que estoy utilizando es éste:

compartirinf.java

```
package cuenta;

public class CompartirInf{ // Esto es el programa principal
public static void main(String[] args){
    Cuenta c=new Cuenta(40,500); 
    Persona p1=new Persona ("Ana",c);
    Persona p2=new Persona ("Juan",c);

    p1.start();
    p2.start();
}


}
```

cuenta.java

```
package cuenta;

class Cuenta{
    private int saldo;
    private int max_saldo;

    //constructor
    Cuenta (int s,int m)
    {
        saldo=s; //inicializa el saldo actual
        max_saldo=m;
    }//--------------------------------------


    //devuelve el saldo 
    int getSaldo()
    {
        return saldo; //
    }



    // sumar la cantidad al saldo
    void sumar(int cantidad)
    {
        saldo += cantidad;
    }//-----------------------------------


    // resta la cantidad al saldo
    void restar(int cantidad)
    {
        saldo=saldo-cantidad;
    }//-----------------------------------


    //comprueba se pueda retirar dinero  y lo retira
        public synchronized void Reintegro(int cant,String nom)
    {
    if (getSaldo()<cant) //si no hay suficiente saldo muestro mensaje
        System.out.println (nom +" quiere retirar "+ cant+" dinero no hay saldo suficiente . Saldo Actual: "+ getSaldo() +"");

    while (getSaldo()<cant){ //si no hay bastante saldo espero
        try {
            wait();
        }catch (InterruptedException e){};
    }

    System.out.println (" Se va a retirar saldo (actual es: "+ getSaldo() +")");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
    restar (cant);
      notifyAll();
    System.out.println (nom +" retira => : "+cant +". Saldo Actual: "+ getSaldo() +"");

    }// fin retirar dinero------------------------------



    //comprueba se pueda insertar dinero  y lo ingresa
    public synchronized void Ingreso(int cant,String nom){


        // Si el saldo es menor a la cantidad límite lo ingresa en la cuenta del objeto persona
        //max_saldo
        if ((cant+getSaldo())<max_saldo) //si no hay suficiente saldo muestro mensaje
        System.out.println (nom +" quiere retirar "+ cant+" dinero es superior al saldo máximo permitido . Saldo Actual: "+ getSaldo() +"");
    while ((cant+getSaldo())<max_saldo){ //si el saldo a ingresar es superior al saldo máximo
        try {
            wait();
        }catch (InterruptedException e){};
    }
        System.out.println (" Se va a añadir saldo (actual es: "+ getSaldo() +")");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
    sumar (cant);
      notifyAll();
    System.out.println (nom +" añade => : "+cant +". Saldo Actual: "+ getSaldo() +"");
    }
    }
```

persona.java

```
package cuenta;

import java.util.Random;
class Persona extends Thread{
private Cuenta c; //declaro objeto cuenta c
private String nom;
int dinero;

//constructor
public Persona (String n, Cuenta c){
//      super(n);
    this.c=c;
    nom=n;
}
//run
public void run(){
Random rnd = new Random();
        dinero=(int)(rnd.nextDouble() * 501.0);
        c.Ingreso (dinero,nom);

        dinero=(int)(rnd.nextDouble() * 501.0);
        c.Reintegro(dinero,nom);

        dinero=(int)(rnd.nextDouble() * 501.0);
        c.Ingreso (dinero,nom);

        dinero=(int)(rnd.nextDouble() * 501.0);
        c.Reintegro(dinero,nom);
    }


}
```

El propósito es conseguir una ejecución donde se muestren también los movimientos de añadir dinero a la cuenta, no sólo de retirada. Sin embargo, parece que el hilo se detiene en algún momento y no muestra las acciones que se supone que debería hacer.

¿Alguna pista sobre qué podría estar fallando?

Comment: El test de hilos no funciona como esperaba. En lugar de mostrar los movimientos que se indican en la clase correspondiente, sólo muestra dos de ellos y se queda parado. Es extraño. Debería completar las operaciones que muestra en el código.

Comment: @heptagono te sale algún error  en el programa

Comment: No sale ningún error, simplemente no continuan los hilos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con los mensajes que recibistes, es sumamente sencillo encontrar la causa del error.

Parte del problema es el manejo de tus hilos, es cierto, pero principalmente es que tu lógica no está bien.  Ambos hilos se trancan en el mismo lugar al ejecutar la primera llamada a `Ingreso`:

```
public synchronized void Ingreso(int cant,String nom){
    // Si el saldo es menor a la cantidad límite lo ingresa en la cuenta del objeto persona
    //max_saldo
    if ((cant+getSaldo())<max_saldo) //si no hay suficiente saldo muestro mensaje
        System.out.println (nom +" quiere retirar "+ cant+" dinero es superior al saldo máximo permitido . Saldo Actual: "+ getSaldo() +"");

    while ((cant+getSaldo())<max_saldo) { //si el saldo a ingresar es superior al saldo máximo
        try {
            wait(); // <------- se tranca aquí!!!
        } catch (InterruptedException e){};
    }

    // ...
}
```

Mas precisamente, se tranca en la llamada a `wait()`. Esto es debido a la condición:

```
cant+getSaldo())<max_saldo
```

... que según los mensajes que recibistes, tienen los valores siguientes:

```
341+40 < 500 // Ana
145+40 < 500 // Juan
```

El primer problema es que no creo que esa sea la condición que deseas aquí. Mas bien, lo mas probable es que es la condición inversa:

```
cant+getSaldo())>max_saldo
```

Pero aun si lo corriges, debes asumir que la condición puede llegar a ser `true` dependiendo del valor de `cant`, lo que lleva al siguiente punto...

Una vez que los 2 hilos hacen el `wait()`, se necesita algún otro hilo que aun esté activo, que retire dinero suficiente, y que llame a `notifyAll()` para que se despierten los hilos trancados. Obviamente, esto no sucede en tu caso porque los 2 hilos quedan trancados al tratar de agregar dinero.

No te puedo dar solución a ese problema, porque creo que, de base, tal vez no has entendido bien el ejercicio que se te pidió.

Pero si al menos inviertes esa condición errónea, deberías ver que los hilos trabajan un poco más que antes. Pero parece que vas a tener que depurar y corregir mas problemas después.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Esa era la clave, ahora el programa funciona tal como estaba establecido. Y sí, en algunos casos, los hilos quedan bloqueados tal como estaba establecido en el enunciado.